# pixels' indices related to Features points detection

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

The code below shows the correspondence  features points between two images. how can i get the pixels' indices of this points? for example, i want to get the pixel's indices(row and column) of the first feature point located into first image.

```
I1=rgb2gray(imread('peau.jpg'));   
I2=imresize(imrotate(I1,-20),1.2);
points1=detectSURFFeatures(I1);
points2=detectSURFFeatures(I2);   
[f1,vpts1] = extractFeatures(I1, points1);     
[f2,vpts2] = extractFeatures(I2, points2);    
[indexPairs,cv] = matchFeatures(f1, f2) ;      
matchedPoints1 = vpts1(indexPairs(:, 1));       
matchedPoints2 = vpts2(indexPairs(:, 2));      
figure; ax = axes;      
showMatchedFeatures(I1,I2,matchedPoints1,matchedPoints2);      
legend(ax,'Matched points 1','Matched points 2');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vpts1` and `vpts2` give you the feature points that were detected between the first and second image respectively.  `indexPairs` returns a `N x 2` matrix where each row gives you which two features matched between the corresponding images.  The first element of each row give you the **index** of which feature in `vpts1` matched with the corresponding feature in `vpts2`, which is the second element of the row.

If you want the actual pixel locations of each feature, you need to access the `Location` field of `vpts1` and `vpts2` respectively, and so:

```
loc1 = vpts1.Location;
loc2 = vpts2.Location;
```

Each will give you a `N x 2` matrix where the first column denotes the `x` or horizontal coordinates while the second column denotes the `y` or vertical coordinates. Now, to get the pixel coordinates of the first feature matched between the two images, simply do:

```
pt1_loc = loc1(indexPairs(1,1),:);
pt2_loc = loc2(indexPairs(1,2),:);
```

`indexPairs(1,1)` and `indexPairs(1,2)` determines the corresponding indices of the features that matched between first and second images, so you use these indices to index into the location arrays of the two images themselves.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting my answer if you no longer need help. That can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of my post, to the left below the up and down voting buttons.  Good luck!